# Printing multiple items in list in different lines

Tags: python, list, for-loop, printing, newline

I need help in a project where i have a board which is in a list of 25 items. How can I print so that it skips line every 5 items. If I have this:

```
    myList = []
    for i in range (1,25):
        myList.append(i)
```

I've looked at `'\n'` and `print(myList, end='')` but I haven't gotten anywhere. I want an end result like this:

```
    1  2  3  4  5
    6  7  8  9  10
    11 12 13 14 15
    16 17 18 19 20
    21 22 23 24 25
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you only printing numbers or any objects? Also do you need the 2-dimensional matrix as result or only the output?

Comment: This is basically a FizzBuzz problem.

Comment: You should read about join() and format() functions.

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a list which goes from 1 to 25 you need to do `range(1, 26)`. Apart from that, you can print it in the format you asked just by doing:

```
numbers = range(1, 26)
for i, elem in enumerate(numbers):
    if i % 5 == 0:
        print()
    print(str(elem).ljust(3), end='')
print()
```

Output:

```
1  2  3  4  5  
6  7  8  9  10 
11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25
```

`enumerate(list)` returns a pair `(index, element)` for every element in the list. `str.ljust(n)` left-justifies the string so that it is `n` characters long, padding the rest with spaces.

EDIT: alternatively, as proposed by @PM_2Ring in the comments:

```
numbers = range(1, 26)
for i, elem in enumerate(numbers, 1):
    print(str(elem).ljust(3), end='\n' if i % 5 == 0 else '')
```

As an alternative to `str(elem).ljust(3)` you can also use `'{:<3}'.format(elem)` (Python 2.7+) or `'{0:<3}'.format(elem)` (Python <2.7)

Comment: Alternatively, supply a start arg of 1 to enumerate: `enumerate(numbers, 1)`, then you can calculate the print `end` arg with a conditional expression: `end = '\n' if i % 5 == 0 else ''`. And then the print call becomes: `print(str(elem).ljust(3), end=end)` or `print('{0:<3}'.format(elem), end=end)`; the format string can be simplified to `'{:<3}'` in Python 2.7+.

Comment: Thanks for your alternative solution, I have added it to the answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(myList)/5+1):
    print " ".join([str(j) for j in myList[5*i:5*i+5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could work with arrays since you can easily reshape them into your board size:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.arange(1,26)
array = array.reshape((5,5))

for line in range(0,5):
    print ' '.join(map(str, array[line,:]))
```

Comment: Using numpy may be a little too advanced for the OP. OTOH, your code is (probably) far more comprehensible than my one-liner. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's an inscrutable functional one-liner:

```
print('\n'.join(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(map('{0:>3}'.format, myList))] * 5))))
```

Note that while this may look cool (to some readers), such dense nested code is really not recommended for use in real programs.

Here's essentially the same algorithm split up to make it more readable, with one of the `map` call converted to a list comprehension:

```
strings = map('{0:>3}'.format, myList)
chunked = zip(*[iter(strings)] * 5)
rows = [''.join(s) for s in chunked]
print '\n'.join(rows)
```

The trickiest part of this algorithm is the `zip(*[iter(strings)] * 5)`. The `[iter(strings)] * 5` part creates a list of 5 references to an iterator over the `strings` iterable. The `*` splat operator passes those references to `zip` as separate arguments. `zip` then creates tuples of length 5 drawing from each of its arguments in turn to fill the tuples. But each of its arguments is a reference to the *same* iterator, `iter(strings)`, thus the contents of that iterator get packaged up into tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over every fifth element and add the in-between numbers:

```
for y in range(1, 26, 5):
    print "\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}".format(y, y+1, y+2, y+3, y+4)
```

For more items per line a double loop is easier:

```
for y in range(1, 26, 5):
    for x in range(y, y+5):
        out += "\t" + str(x)
    out += "\n"
print out
```

I used the tab character here, but you can also use the ljust function of string.

Answer (score 0):

Using some map:

```
myList = range(1, 26)
for line in map(lambda x: myList[x:x+5], range(0, len(myList), 5)):
    print '\t'.join(map(str, line))

1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from math import sqrt

r = range(25)
n =int(sqrt(len(r)))

for i in xrange(0,n):
    print "\t".join([str(s) for s in r[i*n:i*n+n]])
```

Comment: There's no need to import `math` just to get the `sqrt` function; just use the power operator `** 0.5`, which is more efficient. However, calculating square roots is probably unnecessary here: we can assume the number of rows and columns in the board are given.